# Want to allow a form on another domain to submit registration to a drupal form

Tags: forms

I know this is probably a bad idea/imposible, but have to ask.  Is there a way to allow a form on domain "example.com" to submit to the user registration form on "example2.com/user/register".

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it *has* to be possible, because if you don't turn on spam filters you'll get a bazillion fake accounts from automated bots. I'd play around with posting the values from your first site's form using drupal_http_request, something like:
`drupal_http_request($second_site_url, array('method' => 'POST', 'data' => $querystring_from_form_values))`